# Qual è la differenza tra "dal lunedì al venerdì" e "da lunedì a venerdì"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

Ho cercato su vari libri di lingua e ho guardato su internet ma ho davvero trovato poco sulla questione. Queste sono le conclusioni a cui sono giunta, siete d'accordo?

Prima di tutto credo si tratti di piccolezze, probabilmente sfumature che variano da persona a persona, magari anche da regione a regione non saprei … Io vengo dalla Valtellina e secondo me funziona così:

- "DAL lunedì AL venerdì" vuol dire di ogni settimana, sempre. È un caso generale. 
  Esempio: Vado a scuola dal lunedì al venerdì (normalmente). 
  Non direi "Vado a scuola da lunedì a venerdì" …(E voi invece?).  A me non suona idiomatico. Ma è tutta questione di intuizione quindi potrei sbagliarmi!
- "DA lunedì A venerdì" si riferisce secondo me solo alla settimana in corso o alla prossima. 
  Esempio: "Vado a Roma da lunedì a venerdì".

Nel caso di giorni con date fisse e date complete direi "da...a..."
Esempio: L’offerta è valida da giovedì 30 giugno 2016.

Comment: Il mio orecchio concorda col tuo, per quel che vale. La considero una situazione analoga a “Il giovedì vedo gli amici” (ogni settimana) rispetto a “Giovedì vedo gli amici” (questa settimana).

Comment: Concordo. Non ne sono sicuro, ma secondo me _il giovedì_ è una forma contratta di _il (giorno) giovedì_ . Per il resto credo che più che una regola, sia un utilizzo dettato dalla consuetudine.

Comment: Sempre per quel che serve, NGRAM mostra un maggiore uso di da "a": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=da+luned%C3%AC+a+venerd%C3%AC%2Cdal+luned%C3%AC+al+venerd%C3%AC&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cda%20luned%C3%AC%20a%20venerd%C3%AC%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdal%20luned%C3%AC%20al%20venerd%C3%AC%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Sì, concordo con te, io sono di Padova e anche io uso "è aperto dal lunedì al venerdì " per dire che ogni settimana è aperto in quei giorni, mentre uso "andrò a Londra da lunedì a venerdì", per dire un fatto che ci compirà e non ripeterà.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE, @Cristina! Il tuo post è più un commento che una risposta (qui ci aspettiamo una risposta più approfondita e argomentata). Per questa ragione è stato convertito in un commento.

Comment: Ho cercato nel libro *Italiano* di Luca Serianni, ma tutto quanto ho potuto trovare è la conferma di quello che ha detto @DaG: "In alcuni costrutti l'articolo ha valore distributivo: «*il sabato* va dalla nonna» (ogni sabato; invece «sabato va dalla nonna», questo sabato: LEPSCHY-LEPSCHY 1981: 148);" (IV.20).

Comment: Inoltre, nel libro [*Mondi di parole. Grammatica italiana. Per la Scuola media*](https://books.google.es/books?id=9w1dAAAAMAAJ&q=grammatica+italiana+%22dal+luned%C3%AC%22+%22da+luned%C3%AC%22&dq=grammatica+italiana+%22dal+luned%C3%AC%22+%22da+luned%C3%AC%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipz4uKxe7bAhUCI8AKHaYoD9cQ6AEICjAA), di Marino Moretti e Domenico Consonni, ho trovato un esercizio che, tra altre cose, chiede di fare la distinzione tra questi costrutti.

Comment: Se c'è una distinzione, penso non possa essere altra che quella che hai indicato tu (nello stesso esercizio si deve ragionare qual è la differenza tra "lunedì" e "il lunedì". La risposta corretta a questo esercizio dovrebbe essere "La banca è aperta dal lunedì al venerdì" perché la banca apre ogni settimana tra i giorni indicati, ma "Quando sei tornato? Lunedì scorso" perché si riferisce a un lunedì concreto e non a ogni lunedì.

Comment: Qualcuno che ha anche qualche fonte, vedo, potrebbe scrivere una risposta.

Comment: @Charo "Quando sei tornato? Il lunedì scorso" è una risposta perfettamente plausibile.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi complimenti per l'accenno a "il (giorno) giovedì", che ha un significato profondo che pare nessun altro abbia colto.

Comment: Sì, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica, ma l'esercizio che appare nel link del mio commento precedente fa scegliere tra "Lunedì scorso" e "Il lunedì scorso" come risposta alla domanda "Quando sei tornato?".

Comment: @Charo e allora l'esercizio avrebbe dovuto scegliere frasi migliori, perché in questo caso le risposte sono tutt'e due plausibili.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

## dal... al...

> **Per esprimere attività continuativa nel tempo (ripetitiva).**
>
> "Il supermercato è aperto **dal** lunedì **al** venerdì." *(cioè ogni settimana)*
>
> "È obbligatorio avere pneumatici invernali o catene a bordo del veicolo **dal** 15 novembre **al** 15 aprile." *(cioè ogni anno)*

## da... a...

> **Per esprimere attività temporanea.**
>
> "La fiera durerà **da** lunedì **a** mercoledì." *(=solo questa settimana)*
>
> "La mia automobile è stata dal meccanico per 6 giorni, **da** lunedì **a** sabato."

Comment: Sinceramente, @ilMagnifico, non credo che questa risposta aggiunga molto a quello che spiega la propria domanda.

Comment: Sono Italiano e si dice così, è semplicemente idiomatico, così come molte cose anche nella lingua Inglese. Se non credi sia così, citami una fonte perche per me questa risposta è 100% corretta. Saluti

Comment: Dai commenti, puoi vedere che mi sembra molto plausibile che sia così. Ma anche l'OP è italiana e questo lo spiega lei stessa nella domanda, per cui sarebbe preferibile una risposta basata su qualche fonte autorevole.

Comment: "La fiera durerà dal lunedì al mercoledì" e "L'automobile è stata ... per sei giorni, dal lunedì al sabato" sono comunque accettabili, probabilmente perché il contesto non lascia dubbi.